# Adding Folders to a SharePoint 2010 Custom Document Library Template

Tags: visual-studio, custom-list, feature

Although I know it is bad practice, my business requirements dictate to create a default folder structure within a custom document library template. I created the feature in VS including site columns and a content type. How and where in my solution can I add this folder structure to the library template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post it is a cleaner way of doing it, without code:

http://suguk.org/blogs/sharepointhack/archive/2008/01/14/7806.aspx

Or check this other post, this one adds folders to the list definition:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/43f9ec88-5cb2-4f3f-b42a-4fba0cb1f1bf/create-folder-in-list-when-the-list-is-created-by-using-list-definition

Also, you can do it from an event receiver when the list is created:

1. Create an event receiver (ListAdded) for the library definition ([Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadded%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).
2. Add code to create the folder structure.

   `SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListTitle");`

   `SPFolderCollection folderColl = list.RootFolder.SubFolders;`

   `SPFolder newFolder = folderColl.Add(FolderUrl);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the posts, but they both seem to add folders to a List Instance, not a List Template.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you'd probably have a list instance. I edited the answer to add another option. Cheers